# JAX: average per-example gradients different from aggregated gradients

Tags: python, jax

I want to compute per-example gradients to perform per-example clipping before the final gradient descent step.

I wanted to ensure that the per-example gradients are correct. Therefore I implemented this minimal example below to test standard gradient computation and per-example gradient computation with JAX.

The problem I have is, that the average of the per-example gradients differs from the gradients of the standard computation.

Does someone see where I went wrong?

```
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp
from jax import random


def loss(params, x, t):
    w, b = params
    y = jnp.dot(w, x.T) + b
    return ((t.T - y)**2).sum()


def main():

    n_samples = 3
    dims_in = 7
    dims_out = 5

    key = random.PRNGKey(0)

    # Random data
    x = random.normal(key, (n_samples, dims_in), dtype=jnp.float32)
    t = random.normal(key, (n_samples, dims_out), dtype=jnp.float32)
    
    # Random weights
    w = random.normal(key, (dims_out, dims_in), dtype=jnp.float32)
    b = random.normal(key, (dims_out, 1), dtype=jnp.float32)
    params = (w, b)

    # Standard gradient
    reduced_grads = jax.grad(loss)
    dw0, db0 = reduced_grads(params, x, t)
    print(f"{dw0.shape = }") 
    print(f"{db0.shape = }") 

    # Per-example gradients
    perex_grads = jax.vmap(jax.grad(loss), in_axes=((None, None), 0, 0))
    dw1, db1 = perex_grads(params, x, t)
    print(f"{dw1.shape = }") 
    print(f"{db1.shape = }")

    # Gradients are different!
    print(jnp.allclose(dw0, jnp.mean(dw1, axis=0)))  # should be True
    print(jnp.allclose(db0, jnp.mean(db1, axis=0)))  # should be True
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Thank you! Can you explain why the `jax.numpy.atleast_2d()` is necessary? I don"t understand why it does not work without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THe issue is that `vmap` effectively passes 1D inputs to your function, and your loss function operates differently on 1D vs. 2D inputs. You can see this by comparing the following:

```py
print(loss(params, x[0], t[0]))
# 87.5574

print(loss(params, x[:1], t[:1]))
# 18.089672
```

If you inspect the shapes of the intermediate results within the loss function, it should become clear why these differ (e.g. you're summing over a shape `(5, 5)` array of differences instead of a shape `(5, 1)` array of differences).

To use per-example gradients, you'll need to change the implementation of your loss function so that it returns the correct result whether the input is 1D or 2D. The easiest way to do this is probably to use `jnp.atleast_2d` to ensure that the inputs are two-dimensional:

```py
def loss(params, x, t):
    x = jnp.atleast_2d(x)
    t = jnp.atleast_2d(t)
    w, b = params
    y = jnp.dot(w, x.T) + b
    return ((t.T - y)**2).sum()
```

At this point the sum (not the mean) of the per-example gradients will match the full computation:

```py
print(jnp.allclose(dw0, jnp.sum(dw1, axis=0)))
# True
print(jnp.allclose(db0, jnp.sum(db1, axis=0)))
# True
```

Comment: Thank you! Does that mean that JAX accumulates by default the gradients of all samples in a batch? Can this cause numerical overflow for very large batches? And does that mean that I have to adjust the learning rate according to the batch size?

Comment: Well, since your loss function sums over all samples, the gradient will be the sum of gradients of all samples (in general, the gradient of a sum is a sum of gradients). If you use a different accumulation in the loss function, the gradient function will accumulate according to the derivative of whatever accumulation function you use.